# NoClassDefFoundError thrown even when required class is present in classpath

Tags: java, jar

Trying to run jar program and getting class not found error.

As shown in the figure, I have packaged all my dependent jar under lib folder and packaged it inside jar file. 
[image]

**Contents of lib directory:**

[image]

In my manifest.mf file i have

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .\lib\arapi63.jar;.\lib\spring.jar;.\lib\commons-logging.j
 ar;.\lib\log4j.jar;..\conf;.\lib\ojdbc14.jar
Created-By: 1.5.0_12 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: RemedyRecord
```

when i try to run this jar using

```
    java -jar remedyDSTX.jar 
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    
                             com/remedy/arsys/api/ARException
```

No ARException class is present in arapi63.jar which is present in my classpath and so am not sure why is that not referenced here...any thoughts?

**Update:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/arapi63.jar;lib/spring.jar;lib/commons-logging.jar;lib
 /log4j.jar;lib/ojdbc14.jar
Created-By: 1.5.0_12 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: RemedyRecord
```

I updated my manifest as per Jon's comment below but still am getting same error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is the format of your `Class-Path` entry.

As per the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html):

> You specify classes to include in the Class-Path header field in the manifest file of an applet or application. The Class-Path header takes the following form:
>
> Class-Path: jar1-name jar2-name directory-name/jar3-name

Note that this is space-separated, and uses a *forward-slash* between the directory name and the jar file name.

So try a `Class-Path` entry of:

```
Class-Path: lib/arapi63.jar lib/spring.jar lib/commons-logging.jar lib/log4j.jar lib/ojdbc14.jar
```

Note that I've removed the `../conf` part - I don't believe you can add a *directory* to the classpath within a jar file manifest. (I've just tried, and it didn't work.)

Comment: Thanks Jon, i updated my Class-Path entry but still am getting same error no class def found error.